# Finger Isn't Flexing

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

OK, I am new to rigging, so hopefully this is an easy question to answer.  I've got a finger rig, which I made by following a book, to be specific, the Second Edition of Oliver Villar's book, *Learning Blender*.  Here's a picture.

[image: picie]

The big bone, called C_Finger_1, is the bone I use to control the finger.  When I rotate it, it rotates all the fingers, as it should.

However, when I scale it down, it **should** flex the finger, but it doesn't.  The fingers do nothing, except they flip when I scale the C_Finger_1 bone past -1.

I am very much a beginner to this sort of thing.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: maybe share your file, it will help

Comment: sure, but how do I do that?

Comment: use this site: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/   copy the URL of this page and paste it in the field that asks you to do it

Comment: here's the file:    https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6424/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- Deactivate the IK's rotation option (don't know what is for, it's off by default):

[image]

- Bend the bones a bit in *Edit* mode so that Blender knows how to flex it.

[image]

- Once bent, correct the *Pole Angle* of the IK bone:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  It's so nice to see the IK work after your work!

Comment: The reason why the Rotation was checked was because I had turned it on, seeing if it would fix the problem.  Thanks a whole lot for answering so quickly!

Comment: It seems to me, that it should be able to flex without you bending the bones downward.  Seems like you should have a direction of flex or something.  Doesn't really matter a whole lot.  I had a character with fingers that were completely straight.  So what I did was I bent the bones  downward by .001.